# Не могу импортировать ИИ модель с Hugging Face

Tags: python, импорт, pytorch

```
from transformers import AutoFeatureExtractor, AutoModelForObjectDetection

extractor = AutoFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("hustvl/yolos-small")

model = AutoModelForObjectDetection.from_pretrained("hustvl/yolos-small")
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\yolos\feature_extraction_yolos.py", line 31
    FutureWarning,
FutureWarning: The class YolosFeatureExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in version 5 of Transformers. Please use YolosImageProcessor instead.
The `max_size` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in v4.26. Please specify in `size['longest_edge'] instead`.
```

Pytorch установлен, Python 64 bit